# Rのarrayで作成した配列を配列のインデックスとともにデータフレームで出力したい。

Tags: r, array

Rのarrayで作成した配列をデータフレームに出力する方法をご教示ください。

具体的には、n次元配列があったとして、以下のとおり出力させたいと考えています。
1列目には、1次元目のインデックス番号、
2列目には、2次元目のインデックス番号、
・
・
・
n列目には、n次元目のインデックス番号、
n+1列目には、配列の要素

これまでは、配列の次元の数だけforループで行っていましたが、行わないで出力できる
便利な手段などはありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

たとえば、このような配列があったとして、

```
> a <- array(1:30, c(3, 5, 2))  # サイズが 3 x 5 x 2 の3次元配列
> a
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    4    7   10   13
[2,]    2    5    8   11   14
[3,]    3    6    9   12   15

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   16   19   22   25   28
[2,]   17   20   23   26   29
[3,]   18   21   24   27   30
```

`expand.grid()`関数を使えば、インデックスのデータフレームを作成することができます。

```
> indexes <- expand.grid(1:3, 1:5, 1:2)
> result <- cbind(indexes, as.vector(a))
> head(result)
  Var1 Var2 Var3 as.vector(a)
1    1    1    1            1
2    2    1    1            2
3    3    1    1            3
4    1    2    1            4
5    2    2    1            5
6    3    2    1            6
```

この考え方をベースに、どのようなサイズのN次元配列にも適用できるように拡張すると、こんな感じになると思います。

```
> cbind(do.call(expand.grid, lapply(dim(a), seq_len)), as.vector(a))
```

あるいは

```
> library(dplyr)
> lapply(dim(a), seq_len) %>% do.call(expand.grid, .) %>% cbind(as.vector(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

以下は `as.data.frame.table()` を使う方法です。

```
> arr <- array(1:24, dim=c(3, 4, 2))
> arr
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   13   16   19   22
[2,]   14   17   20   23
[3,]   15   18   21   24

> df <- as.data.frame.table(arr, base=list(as.character(1:max(dim(arr)))), responseName='value')
> df
   Var1 Var2 Var3 value
1     1    1    1     1
2     2    1    1     2
3     3    1    1     3
4     1    2    1     4
5     2    2    1     5
6     3    2    1     6
7     1    3    1     7
8     2    3    1     8
9     3    3    1     9
10    1    4    1    10
11    2    4    1    11
12    3    4    1    12
13    1    1    2    13
14    2    1    2    14
15    3    1    2    15
16    1    2    2    16
17    2    2    2    17
18    3    2    2    18
19    1    3    2    19
20    2    3    2    20
21    3    3    2    21
22    1    4    2    22
23    2    4    2    23
24    3    4    2    24
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。いずれの方法でもできました。大変助かります。